# ngram not working on symbol elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

These are my settings:

```
"nGram_filter": {
      "type": "nGram",
      "min_gram": 2,
      "max_gram": 20,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit",
        "punctuation",
        "symbol"
      ]
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "nGram_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "nGram_filter"
      ]
    },
    "whitespace_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I'm using

```
"index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
"search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
```

But I'm not able to get the ngram on symbols like $, attaching the curl request

```
_analyze ? analyzer = nGram_analyzer ' -d '$100 '
{"tokens":[
  {"token":"10","start_offset":1,"end_offset":4,"type":"word","position":1},
  {"token":"100","start_offset":1,"end_offset":4,"type":"word","position":1},
  {"token":"00","start_offset":1,"end_offset":4,"type":"word","position":1}
 ]}
```

It is not giving me $ sign in the token. I will really appreciate if you can tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: hmm works for me which version of elasticsearch , could you try the following with url encoding: `curl -XGET "http://<host::port>/<index>/_analyze?analyzer=nGram_analyzer&text=%24100"`

Comment: That works for me, too (tested on 1.4.5, 1.5.2, 1.6.1, 1.7.1)